# Distributed CMS or content management platform?

Tags: content-management-system

I have been trying to find an open source or affordable platform / CMS that is distributed.

And by distributed I mean that there is a single control panel with all the content, but you can have multiple websites on multiple web hosts that query an API that holds this content. Not the usual "one install, multiple websites" as you can do with Wordpress MU.

Ideally there would be an API that the website can connect to and get the data, or use push technology from the control panel once new content is added.

If there is no client side platform built but there is a sophisticated content management platform with an API that allows me to build my own client/website connecting to it, that would be fine too.

Does anyone have tips if there is such a thing?

Comment: Looking for the same. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Govento CMS is a distributed CMS, that allow you, to manage all projects with a single installation and present your content via push publishing dynamic and current on different remote delivery-platforms.

german:  http://goventocms.com
or english: 
http://translate.google.de/translate?hl=en&sl=de&u=http://govento.de/&prev=search

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?